# SQL Server : query to get sum of values in Col1 of Table1 for a condition in Col2 of Table 2

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I have two tables. Table1 has Col1 and Col2 and Table2 has Col1 and Col3.
So col1 name is common in both the tables.

I need a query that should do sum of matched strings for common ROW IDs (Table1-col1 value)

Attached this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can access columns using [table name].[column name]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements, please?  Which column or columns are you trying to sum?  Which column contains the data you're conditioning on?  Which columns join `Table1` to `Table2`?
  Your title implies `Col2` is in `Table2`, but the question says it's in `Table1`.

Comment: My col1 in both the table contains same IDs. So this is a common column to use JOIN. Query that I need is T1.C2 has entries like "success", "Faiure", which appear many times and T2.C2 has all cost entries in numbers. So, I want to show output for Success, total cost was add all the costs that is inline with T1C1 IDs and for failure 'total cost' that is inline with T2C1 IDs. So, finally I will get total costs of all IDs in success ROW and total cost of failures in Failure row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this (udpated for nulls and empty spaces):

```
SELECT 'Success', SUM(t2.Col2) FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 WHERE t1.Col2 = 'Success' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Failure', SUM(t2.Col2) FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 WHERE t1.Col2 = 'Failure' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NULL', SUM(t2.Col2) FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 WHERE t1.Col2 IS NULLUNION ALL
SELECT 'EMPTY SPACE', SUM(t2.Col2) FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 WHERE t1.Col2 = ' '
```

will give you two rows with the results you wanted.

- `UNION ALL` simply concatenates two or more rows (with the same columns); `ALL` tells to ignore duplicates (which is not a concern here and actually speeds up performance)
- `SUM` of course sums all cells in a column
- `JOIN` [will "merge" your tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

> A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

Comment: Yes, i tried and got TYPE error here it is :: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Success' to data type int.

Comment: Well yeah, 'Success' is a string (varchar or nvarchar I guess, that's the type of your "Result" column), you can't use it in a sum. Right?

Comment: But my requirement is to not convert anything but just add all the amounts that are in line with ROWID which is in line with Success and some ROWID are in line with FAILURES. So, my table 1 has only the ROWID in one column and Results(succes, Failure) in other column and my Table two has ROWID in one column  and amounts in other column. I am trying to form a join query based on ROWID as this is the common column between two tables and then return two columns one for total success=total amounts and another for total Failures= total amount

Comment: I edited my answer. Did I understand what you needed? Does it work?

Comment: Hey FracescoB - you are awesome man. good job!. yes it works. last clarification i have is... i added another select to look for 3rd value which is showing as NULL along with Success&Failures. But this does not sum the amount and just gives me NULL value. 

so, how to expand your query to look for other values like 'NULL', 'EMPTY SPACE' ?

Comment: I edited my answer to take that into account, let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i tried that already but it does not SUM for Empty and NULL, for these two it just lists as NULL in Amount Column. so, i feel there is a special way of handling these.

Comment: Does Amount contain NULL?

Comment: good question, sorry my bad, so yes amount column has NULL and actually amounts too. its like real amounts and some values are NULL.

Comment: So do you need anything else about this?

Comment: i even tried this to do sum only when there is no NULL but even this does not help: 

SELECT 'NULL', SUM(t2.Col2) FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 WHERE t1.Col2 IS NULL AND t2.Col2 IS NOT NULL UNION ALL

Comment: Yes, so how would I calculate amounts for NULL and Empty space in columns? because NULL and Empty space represent valid accounts and they have costs. All that value is indicating is we were not able to send report and hence gets NULL or empty but we will need to calculate amount for these.

Comment: But if the amount is NULL... what should it be instead? What kind of result would you like?

Comment: so  the column has NULL and other valid amounts as well. it should just ignore null or consider null as 0 and do the sum